# Difference between `closed_iota` and `iota`?

Tags: c++, range-v3

What is the difference between `closed_iota` and `iota`, from the ranges-v3 library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one follows the standard C++ way of expressing a range - defaulting to right-hand side open range. The first one is inclusive.

`iota` takes two arguments: `start` and `end`. It produces elements from `start` to `end` *without* including `end`.

`closed_iota` takes two arguments: `start` and `end`. It produces elements from `start` to `end` *including* `end` value.

Example: `iota(1, 5)` represents a range consisting of `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, and `closed_iota(1, 5)` represents a range consisting of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

You want both of them because, by default, we expect things to be right-hand side exclusive, but there are times when you want *the whole range of values*. In that case you need `closed_iota`.

There are inconsistencies, however - look at `std::uniform_xxx_distribution`s.

Comment: Hi, i think you forgot to say what is the data type for the params. which datatype don't and can cause errors.

Comment: @NguyenManh no such question was asked, thus I didn't expand on that topic. But those those who are curious, the values need to be [weakly incremebtable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable).

Answer (score 2):

Both `closed_iota` and `iota` take 2 arguments, a `begin` value, and an `end` value, and produce a range of values containing all the values between `begin` and `end`.

The former generates all values from `begin` to `end` *inclusive*, and the latter does the same, but the last value, i.e. `end`, is excluded.

You might be wondering what the point of `closed_iota` is, since you could always do this transformation:

```
// from this
closed_iota(begin, end);
// to this
iota(begin, end + 1);
```

One reason is this transformation is *not* always possible. e.g. consider what happens when `end` is the largest possible `int`. Then the second version would invoke UB when doing `end + 1`. You can solve this particular case by using `closed_iota`.